# wanted to create route like this but not able to find exact parameter value in controller?

Tags: laravel, routes

Having issue in slug1 and slug2

`Route::get("/something/{slug1}-{slug2}-sample-sample" , "Controller@Method")->where(['slug1'=>'[a-z0-9-]+', 'slug1'=> '[a-z0-9-]+');`

where slugs can be xxx-yyy or only xxx

I'm getting only one parameter value

Answer (score 1):

Because you put `slug1` twice in the `where` method, so your route is only checking against the first slug twice, also you forgot to close the array :

```
Route::get("/something/{slug1}-{slug2}" , "Controller@Method")->where(['slug1'=>'([\w]+[-]{1}[\w]+)', 'slug2'=> '([\w]+[-]{1}[\w]+)']);
```

If afterwards you want to get those values in your controller using your `Method`, you can pass those slugs in that method as a parameter:

```
public function Method($slug1, $slug2)
{
    dump($slug1, $slug2); //will display both slug's value
}
```

If you want to [pass them to your view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views) :

```
public function Method($slug1, $slug2)
{
    return view('your-blade-view', ['slug1' => $slug1, 'slug2' => $slug2]);
}
```

And to retrieve them from your view

```
{{ $slug1 }} //echo first slug
{{ $slug2 }} //echo second slug
```

**Update :** this is the REGEX you were looking for : `->where(['slug1'=>'([\w]+[-]{1}[\w]+)', 'slug2'=> '([\w]+[-]{1}[\w]+)']);` see [here](https://regex101.com/r/0pVPfQ/1).

Comment: bcoz both are different i.e slug1 is belong to store and slug2 belongs to any product.

Comment: I have updated my answer, tell me if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: my route is 
Route::get("/implement/{brandSlug}-{slug}" , "TractorImplements@SingleImplementNew");

My Url is : https://example.com/implement/maschio-gaspardo-barbi-180

slug1 id = maschio-gaspardo , slug2 = barbi-180
 but i m not getting these value in controller , i m not able to separate them in controller

Comment: Oh, so you're looking a REGEX to match those values, ok, I'll look at it and come up with a solution.

Comment: its matched for  example.com/implement/maschio-gaspardo-barbi-180
but these kind of route not matched example.com//implement/agristar-powervator-6-feet-42-blades-718v 

**slug1** can be either `abc-def` or `abc`
**slug2** can be either `abc-def-ghihg-7787` or `abc-rwtrt` or any thing in this pattern

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying, please rephrase it in an understandable way, what's your exactly desired output?

Comment: `My URL is: www.exmple.com/brand-slug-some-product-slug`

slug1 =  brand-slug
slug2 = some-product-slug

**case 1** : `slug1` can be one word
ie: www.exmple.com/brandSlug-some-product-slug

**case 2** : `slug1` can be more than one word as shown below
ie: www.exmple.com/brand-slug-some-product-slug

**case 3** : `slug2` can be more than one word or two or more than three
ie: www.exmple.com/brand-slug-some-product-slug

Now i have to catch `slug1` value and `slug2` value in controller 

I am not able to get right slug values

Comment: Well, as slug1 and slug2 can be on or more words you won't be able to tell which one is which unless you change the requirements for one of those slugs so we can differenciate them and make different REGEX accordingly.